# Get rid of default styling on iPad1 (border radius)

Tags: css, ipad

I got a quantity box where you can change the amount of products in your basket.
It looks fine in all browsers, except when I view the website on my iPad 1. It has weird rounded corners there.

I found here that you had to use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

On input in css, but that's not doing it for me.

This is what I got in my css:

```
input{
    -webkit-appearance: none;   
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `-webkit-border-radius:0px;`

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the rounded border, the three input fields still have a way bigger padding then on my destkop browser.

I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes.